# Binomial Coefficent; cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, variables, coefficients

i have the following code that outputs the binomial coefficient of 2 numbers. I would like to include the two numbers in a statement that is printed out along with the overall result but i am receiving the following error:

_ cannot be resolved to a variable

here is my code:

```
public class BinomialCoefficients
{
    private static long binomial(int n, int k)
    {
        if (k>n-k)
            k=n-k;

        long b=1;
        for (int i=1, m=n; i<=k; i++, m--)
            b=b*m/i;
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("The Binomial Coefficients of" + n + "and " + k + " is: " + binomial(15, 4));
    }
}
```

any help?

Comment: how can you expect compiler to resolve n and k variables in your main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't define variables `n` and `k` in your `main` method.

Declare variables

```
int n = 15;
int k = 4;
```

Then also use these in your call to the `binomial` method, rather than hard-coding `15` and `4`:

```
System.out.println("The Binomial Coefficients of" + n + "and " + k + " is: " + binomial(n, k));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are getting this compilation error in your `main`method. You have to declare the variables `k` and `n` before using them in `main`.

You can update your code as follows:

```
public class BinomialCoefficients
{
    private static long binomial(int n, int k)
    {
        if (k>n-k)
            k=n-k;

        long b=1;
        for (int i=1, m=n; i<=k; i++, m--)
            b=b*m/i;
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 15;
        int k = 4;
        System.out.println("The Binomial Coefficients of" + n + "and " + k + " is: " + binomial(n, k));
    }
}
```